# create ImageViews programatically 2 wide and infinitely tall

Tags: java, android

Hi I would like to create a table style of ImageView's where the images are 2 wide, but infinitely tall. I am getting the images from an array. I am able to get them to display in a row either horizontal or vertical but never 2 wide and endlessly wide.

This list will never need to be more than say 10 or 20 items so it doesn't need to be an endless scrolling view

Something like this:

```
|----------|----------|
|          |          |
|----------|----------|
|          |          |
|----------|----------|
|          |          |
|----------|----------|
```

The code I currently have is:

```java
LinearLayout allPromotions = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.allpromos_images);

allPromotions.removeAllViewsInLayout();

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(60), dpToPx(60));

lp.setMargins(dpToPx(8), dpToPx(8), dpToPx(8), dpToPx(8));


for (int i = 0; i < home.promoItemsArray.size(); i++) {
    ImageView promoImage = new ImageView(AllPromosActivity.this);
    PromoItem item = home.promoItemsArray.get(i);

    request.getImage(item.imageUrl, promoImage);
    promoImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    promoImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
    allPromotions.addView(promoImage);
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** Another thing that my code does not currently have is that I would like it spread evenly across the screen (right now its about Icon size - which I aware that the setting `LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(60), dpToPx(60))` sets it to 60dp x 60dp